# Hive doesn't recognize jar

Tags: maven, hadoop, hive

I started working with Hive just recently, so I may be a little new to this, I compiled a jar using Maven Build and for some reason when I am trying to add it in the hive, it won't work. I get the following error:
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: ex-0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist.
I uploaded the file using hue, and I can find it if I do dfs -ls in hive.

What am I missing? (I was able to load a jar I got online)

Thanks!

Comment: did you do add jar jarname before the hive query?

Comment: does the jar you built have any additional dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find your jar by `-ls`ing to it and it was properly built, usually this error is cause by incorrectly putting quotes around the path to the jar.

**Incorrect:**

```
add jar '/root/complete/path/to/jar.jar';
```

**Correct:**

```
add jar /root/complete/path/to/jar.jar;
```